# Netflix Gateway implementation

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-java, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

So I was reading an article about how Netflix scales its API with graphql federation. In second part of this article I noticed a fact that Netflix has developed a special Gateway based on apollo federation specification.

https://netflixtechblog.com/how-netflix-scales-its-api-with-graphql-federation-part-2-bbe71aaec44a

I searched whole Internet but I couldn't find the implementation.
I want to know did they expose the implementation and if they did where can I find it?

Comment: The [transcript of the QCon Plus talk recorded on November 23, 2020](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/netflix-api-graphql-federation/) reads "*Our gateway is not currently open source, but it is something that we're definitely open to. It's been on our roadmap. If this is something that you'd be interested in using or collaborating on, then do let us know, and they'll help us prioritize the work of supporting that as an open source project.*"